# change class based on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, navigation

Basically I have a single page site that scrolls when the user clicks on the navigation menu.

```
<div id="mainnav">
<ul id="nav">

<li class="fadertwo"><a id="tst" onclick="CngClass(this);" href="index.html#abouttwo">About</a></li>

<li class="faderthree"><a id="sec"  onclick="CngClass(this);" href="index.html#second">Curriculum vitae</a></li>
<li class="faderfour"><a id="third" onclick="CngClass(this);" href="index.html#thirdtwo">contact</a></li>

</ul>



</div> <!-- end mainnav -->
```

Using jquery (which im totally new to) it adds a class when the user clicks on each link.
Basically it transitions the background position.

```
    .active {
background-position:bottom;
text-decoration:none;
 -webkit-transition: .3s linear;
       -moz-transition: .3s linear;
         -o-transition: .3s linear;
            transition: .3s linear;
}
```

Background is a 10px img repeating along the top.

```
#tst {background-image:url(../_images/whiteb.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
 -webkit-transition: .3s linear;
       -moz-transition: .3s linear;
         -o-transition: .3s linear;
            transition: .3s linear;

}


#sec {background-image:url(../_images/blackb.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
 -webkit-transition: .3s linear;
       -moz-transition: .3s linear;
         -o-transition: .3s linear;
            transition: .3s linear;

}

#third {background-image:url(../_images/greenb.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x; 
 -webkit-transition: .3s linear;
       -moz-transition: .3s linear;
         -o-transition: .3s linear;
            transition: .3s linear;}
```

Now the jquery magic -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var Lst;

function CngClass(obj){
 if (typeof(obj)=='string') obj=document.getElementById(obj);
 if (Lst) Lst.className='';
 obj.className='active';
 Lst=obj;
}


</script>
```

It works great changing the background position in a really smooth way when the user clicks it, but of course doesn't change based on the user scrolling the page naturally.
Now, I could set the body overflow to :hidden; and 'fix' that, but it's a bit hacky and will limit the content area and overall site layout.

What I'd like to do is use jquery to add the class .active to the a tag based on scroll position so it changes anyway.

I've looked around for hours and tried different things but my (lackof) knowledge of jquery limits me somewhat it implementing anything I find effectively.

Can anyone offer any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at scrollspy

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

or

https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy

Comment: "can't get it to work" is not much information to assist you here. How far did you get? What specific problems did you run into?

Comment: As in nothing happens when I try to do it, sorry but I can't explain it better than that.

Comment: What is it you try to do that nothing happens? Did you load something on your page, write some html or javascript, put some tags on a page, have a smoke. seriously post the code of your attempts and somebody might help.

Comment: This is more of a 'how to' question, because frankly I'm totally lost when it comes to implementing javascript and jquery despite my best efforts to do so. You don't need to do it for me, just some pointers beyond some links would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you even looked at the example and Tried it yourself on this link I gave you? https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy. But it sounds like you need to.do some basic javascript / jquery tutorials before attempting advanced stuff like scroll tracking. Understand the asynchronous patterns that jquery uses. Once you get that the example in the link is obvious..

Comment: You're probably right, I'm going too far too fast without a foundation understanding!

Answer (score 0):

Or have a look at
http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/